# How do I use Excel to insert blocks into AutoCAD drawings?

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I'm trying to use Excel to create AutoCAD drawings. I have a list of product numbers and I'd like to use VBA so that upon hitting a button it will find a block or a drawing file of every product on the list and paste them into an AutoCAD drawing (to a specific point would be a bonus).

So far I've found code that will read from two columns in Excel and will plot a polyline in ACAD using those columns as coordinates. It's very simple but not exactly what I want. Does anyone have suggestions or example code that does something similar? I've found some online using the "ThisDrawing." object but Excel isn't recognizing that so I've reached a stand still. I have all day tomorrow to work on it, so I'll be doing a lot more searching, but any help is definitely appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You don't use Excel to create drawings, you use AutoCAD to read an Excel file.

Comment: I appreciate the correction, but my question remains the same. How do I set up an Excel file so that, when ACAD reads it, it will automatically populate an ACAD drawing with blocks?

Comment: Essentially, the Excel spreadsheet would have to have all of the properties of the blocks you are inserting into the drawing. This is non-trivial, the sort of thing you pay a developer to do for you if you can't do it yourself. Read the autocad tag wiki for other sources / forums to search for AutoCAD programming info.

Comment: You must find the `Autocad.Interop` and `Autocad.Interop.Common` libraries (dlls) in your PC and add references to them in VBA (tools, references). Only then, the autocad objects will work in Excel. Even So, "ThisDrawing" will not, it only works inside autocad VBA. You can use the autocad application to open files though.

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk provide free downloads on their website so that you can add the VBA IDE into AutoCAD.

Then, inside the AutoCAD IDE you start a new VBA project.
Add a reference to your Excel library so that you can read the Excel spreadsheet.

You need to look up on:

```
ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock
```

In the AutoCAD VBA manual. It tells you what various parameters. But they are straightforward - origin, scale, rotation, path to block.

When you call the `InsertBlock` routine it will create a `AcadBlockReference` object. You can do any further customization on that object.

Comment: You can also access the AutoCAD ActiveX API (the API that VBA uses) from Excel using (out-of-process) ActiveX Automation of AutoCAD. Same API calls apply as Andrew mentions.